# How do I find the hooks used by this module?

Tags: 8, hooks

How can I find out what hooks are available in the [Entity Clone module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_clone)? I want to modify the entity after it is cloned to change its author and workflow state.

Comment: What hook are you looking for specifically?

Answer (score 4):

As @Kevin says, modules should have a modulename.api.php file with examples that implement hooks that the module provides.

When this file is not available you can search for the code that creates a hook in Drupal.

#### Drupal 8

Look for following functions of the [ModuleHandlerInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandlerInterface.php/interface/ModuleHandlerInterface/8.2.x), usually implemented by the [ModuleHandler](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Extension!ModuleHandler.php/class/ModuleHandler/8.2.x) class:

- invokeAll
- alter

Using grep it's easy; just go to the module's root directory and execute:

```
 grep '\->invokeAll(\|\->alter(' * -r
```

This command looks for the strings `->invokeAll` (creates regular hooks) and `->alter` (creates alter hooks).

For example, if you use this grep command with core's module User you get:

```
src/Entity/User.php:    \Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter('user_format_name', $name, $this);
user.module:  \Drupal::moduleHandler()->invokeAll('user_login', array($account));
user.module:    \Drupal::moduleHandler()->invokeAll('user_cancel', array($edit, $account, $method));
user.module:  \Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter('user_cancel_methods', $methods);
user.module:  \Drupal::moduleHandler()->invokeAll('user_logout', array($user));
```

So, this module creates the following hooks:

- hook_user_format_name_alter
- hook_user_login
- hook_user_logout
- hook_user_cancel
- hook_user_cancel_methods_alter

#### Drupal 7

Same procedure, but in this case you have to look for the functions `module_invoke_all()` and `drupal_alter()`.

```
grep 'module_invoke_all\|drupal_alter' * -r
```

Keep in mind that this method is not 100% reliable, as some modules use their own hook creation implementation (I've seen this in Drupal 7 mainly), but it's a good starting point if the said `modulename.api.php` file is missing.

#### Entity Clone

Unfortunately Entity Clone doesn't create any hook, and the command yields no results.

#### invoke

There are certain hooks that are only invoked in a particular module, see [ModuleHandler::invoke](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Extension!ModuleHandler.php/function/ModuleHandler%3A%3Ainvoke/8.2.x) and [module_invoke](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_invoke/7.x). As they only affects certain modules they are less used than regular ones (they are some kind of internal use hooks).

Answer (score 0):

Some modules provide a `modulename.api.php` file detailing any hooks, such as info hooks, theme hooks, and alter hooks, that a developer can use to integrate or extend. It is usually found in the root of the module.

It doesn't look like Entity Clone provides such a file.

Comment: I want to modify the entity after its cloned to change it author and workflow state.  how can I do this if there is no hook available?

Comment: Sounds like you could use the standard hook_entity_presave? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x